# sorting js array of objects by frequency of a field

Tags: javascript

Is there a possible way for me to sort an array of Objects by the frequency of a field, and then make a new list as a leader-board of that frequency? For example, I'm trying to figure out in a library who was the most published author, so starting with an original array of books I get a sorted array of the most frequent authors.

Thanks

Comment: Always give sample in and output

Comment: *`Is there a possible way for me to sort an array of Objects by the frequency of a field, and then make a new list as a leader-board of that frequency?`* ----- **YES Possible**

Answer (score 0):

I think your data looks like this:

```
var books=[{author:"Steven",title:"sth"},...];
```

So you could simply store a book count for each author:

```
var bookcountof={};

books.forEach(function(book){
 if(!bookcountof[book.author]) bookcountof[book.author]=0;
 bookcountof[book.author]++;//increase
});
```

To get the number of books, e.g. steven, you can simply do:

```
bookcountof["Steven"];
```

Now we need an Array so that we can sort:

```
var topauthors=Object.keys(bookcountof).map(name=>({name,count:bookcountof[name]}));

topauthors.sort((a,b)=>a.count-b.count);
```

Comment: @victor youre welcome ;) if youve collected 15 reputation, you can reward answerers with upvotes...